How to let QProcess class emit output signal immediately when sub process running the print statement
I have following code in the constructor of MainWindow class:
 QObject::connect(&m_pythonProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(on_ready_read()));


Then I created a slot memeber function in the MainWindow class:
void RunTestCaseThread::on_ready_read()
{
    qDebug() << this->m_pythonProcess.readAllStandardOutput();
}

I also add following code:
m_pythonProcess.star("python.exe test.py");
m_pythonProcess.waitForStarted();

The code of test.py is as follows:
from time import sleep

i = 0
while i < 10:
    print(f"test case {i}")
    i += 1
    sleep(2)

What I want is my qt software could get readyReadStandardOutput signal when the test.py running to the line print(f"test case {i}"), but in my code I get readyReadStandardOutput signal when test.py was finished.
Can anyone help me about that?

By default the python output is buffered. Try to add the -u flag.

You are right python.exe -u test.py could solve this problem. Thanks so much.
